# get count by datetime column with month and year on group by in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using xamarin forms. I have some issue on datetime field in SQLite group by.
The following Table in I am using:

```
public class DataTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int WorkOrderId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> TargetDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I am having the data for the above table like follow:

```
ID  WorkOrderId     TargetDateTime 
1   835     2018-08-16 00:00:00.000
2   836     2018-08-27 00:00:00.000
3   837     2018-09-18 00:00:00.000
4   838     2018-09-29 00:00:00.000
5   839     2018-10-15 00:00:00.000
6   840     2018-11-19 00:00:00.000
```

I want to Group by this table by month and year of TargetDateTime Column like below:

```
MonthYear   count
07-2018     2
08-2018     2
09-2018     1
10-2018     1
```

For View purpose for this Table i am using below:

```
public class DataTableSummary
    {
        public string YearMonth { get; set; }
        public string MonthYear { get; set; }
        public int RecordCount { get; set; }

    }

var com = conn.Query<DataTableSummary>("SELECT strftime('%m-%Y',TargetDateTime) as YearMonth,count(*) as RecordCount FROM DataTable group by strftime('%m-%Y',TargetDateTime)");
```

But it is not working. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `TargetDateTime` is of type string with format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

with `strftime`

```sql
select
  strftime('%m-%Y', TargetDateTime) as YearMonth,
  count(1) as RecordCount
from DataTable
group by YearMonth
```

```
$ sqlite3
sqlite> select strftime('%m-%Y', '2023-12-20 12:34');
12-2023
```

with `substr`

```sql
select
  substr(TargetDateTime, 0, 8) as YearMonth,
  count(1) as RecordCount
from DataTable
group by YearMonth
```

```
$ sqlite3
sqlite> select substr('2023-12-20 12:34', 0, 8);
2023-12
```

see also [How to Group by Month in SQLite](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-group-by-month-in-sqlite/)